# Javascript to return first and last name in a array of object getaccountfullname

Tags: javascript, object, mapping

```js
const accounts = [
  {
    id: "5f446f2ecfaf0310387c9603",
    picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/esther.tucker@zillacon.me",
    age: 25,
    name: {
      first: "Esther",
      last: "Tucker",
    },
    company: "ZILLACON",
    email: "esther.tucker@zillacon.me",
    registered: "Thursday, May 28, 2015 2:51 PM",
  },
  {
    id: "5f446f2ed46724f41c9fc431",
    picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/ferrell.morris@ecolight.com",
    age: 35,
    name: {
      first: "Ferrell",
      last: "Morris",
    },
    company: "ECOLIGHT",
    email: "ferrell.morris@ecolight.com",
    registered: "Thursday, February 8, 2018 1:16 PM",
  }]

function getAccountFullNames(accounts) {

 
}

return accounts.name.first + account.name.last
```

What it to return Esther Tucker

Comment: It looks like you forgot to put your code *inside* the function...

Comment: Aside from that, `accounts` is an *array*.  Do you mean for your function to *always* access the first element of that array?  Are you familiar with how to use arrays?  Have you looked up any tutorials or examples of that?  Please clarify the specific question you are asking about your code.

Comment: Thanks David it  was my first time posting so I gave my try attempt afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array::map()` and object destructuring on an array item argument:

```js
function getAccountFullNames(accounts) {
  return accounts.map(({name:{first, last}}) => first + ' ' + last);
}

console.log(getAccountFullNames(accounts));
```

```html
<script>
const accounts = [ { id: "5f446f2ecfaf0310387c9603", picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/esther.tucker@zillacon.me", age: 25, name: { first: "Esther", last: "Tucker", }, company: "ZILLACON", email: "esther.tucker@zillacon.me", registered: "Thursday, May 28, 2015 2:51 PM", }, { id: "5f446f2ed46724f41c9fc431", picture: "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/75/ferrell.morris@ecolight.com", age: 35, name: { first: "Ferrell", last: "Morris", }, company: "ECOLIGHT", email: "ferrell.morris@ecolight.com", registered: "Thursday, February 8, 2018 1:16 PM", }]

</script>
```